# Skype screen-sharing doesn't work properly

Tags: skype, 15.10

I'm trying to use Skype's screen sharing feature but whenever I start the feature, the only thing the person I'm Skyping gets is just a frozen frame of the last moment from my camera before I attempted the screen-share.

It was working properly on Windows on the same computer.

I am thinking it is about some visual drivers or packages but that's just a thought.

Any advice?

Comment: Personally, I'd say find another program. Skype for Linux is so badly outdated, it's a wonder it's even compatible anymore. In fact, the only supported OSes that aren't EOL are Debian 7 and Ubuntu 12.04. Yeah, I guess this doesn't help much...

Comment: @SuperSluether - I have it working on 14.04 x64....

Answer (score 5):

Skype for Ubuntu is unfortunately outdated. It does not receive any more updates and has certain broken parts.

Here's a list of additional software you could use to accomplish the task at hand -->

1) [Guacamole](http://guac-dev.org)

2) [appear.in](https://appear.in)

3) [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en)

The other option is to use remote desktop over VNC. Its simple and does not require the installation of other third-party applications. [Guide to setup VNC.](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-logmein-alternatives-ubuntu/)

The most recommended option would be [Jitsu video bridge](https://meet.jit.si/). It is a video chat client that will also provide you with the option to share the desktop beside some other features. It could be the alternative for skype that you are looking and it works directly from within the browser.

Edit: Google Hangouts also support screen sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Skype for Linux is not as good as the ones for Windows or OSX. For Linux, it seems like a stripped down version and even after that, some features do not work. Looks like Microsoft is not making real efforts to solve the problems faced by Linux users let alone adding new features.

I too would advise you to find another program. Teamviewer's presentation mode seems good for personal use and it works well for Windows as well as Linux based systems.

You can also try and find some open source programs for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I deleted the skype folder from :`~/.config/`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `/home/username/.skype` start skype, log in and screen sharing should work normally

Answer (score 0):

Skype for Linux is practically unsupported and unmantained. The best alternative in my opinion is Google's Hangouts. You can even invite people sending them a link and you will not need to install anything (Although chrome is a good suggestion).

If you insist, you may find some tutorials on how to run Skype for Windows though Wine and PlayOnLinux. Still, I gave up a moved to Hangouts.